# How to install javac on Linux Mint

Tags: python, apk, buildozer

I wrote a small code in Python for android, when compiling the code in the apk file, an error occurs

```
# Java compiler (javac) not found, please install it.
```

Writes that it is necessary to install javaс. I already installed java 14.0.2, but the error still comes out. I do all this in Linux Mint, if you write java in the console, it will give the following:

```
Usage: javac <options> <source files>
where possible options include:


@<filename>                  Read options and filenames from file
  -Akey[=value]                Options to pass to annotation processors
  --add-modules <module>(,<module>)*
        Root modules to resolve in addition to the initial modules, or all modules
        on the module path if <module> is ALL-MODULE-PATH.
  --boot-class-path <path>, -bootclasspath <path>
        Override location of bootstrap class files
  --class-path <path>, -classpath <path>, -cp <path>
        Specify where to find user class files and annotation processors
  -d <directory>               Specify where to place generated class files
  -deprecation
        Output source locations where deprecated APIs are used
  --enable-preview
        Enable preview language features. To be used in conjunction with either -source or --release.
  -encoding <encoding>         Specify character encoding used by source files
  -endorseddirs <dirs>         Override location of endorsed standards path
  -extdirs <dirs>              Override location of installed extensions
  -g                           Generate all debugging info
  -g:{lines,vars,source}       Generate only some debugging info
  -g:none                      Generate no debugging info
  -h <directory>
        Specify where to place generated native header files
  --help, -help, -?            Print this help message
  --help-extra, -X             Print help on extra options
  -implicit:{none,class}
        Specify whether or not to generate class files for implicitly referenced files
  -J<flag>                     Pass <flag> directly to the runtime system
  --limit-modules <module>(,<module>)*
        Limit the universe of observable modules
  --module <module>(,<module>)*, -m <module>(,<module>)*
        Compile only the specified module(s), check timestamps
  --module-path <path>, -p <path>
        Specify where to find application modules
  --module-source-path <module-source-path>
        Specify where to find input source files for multiple modules
  --module-version <version>
        Specify version of modules that are being compiled
  -nowarn                      Generate no warnings
  -parameters
        Generate metadata for reflection on method parameters
  -proc:{none,only}
        Control whether annotation processing and/or compilation is done.
  -processor <class1>[,<class2>,<class3>...]
        Names of the annotation processors to run; bypasses default discovery process
  --processor-module-path <path>
        Specify a module path where to find annotation processors
  --processor-path <path>, -processorpath <path>
        Specify where to find annotation processors
  -profile <profile>
        Check that API used is available in the specified profile
  --release <release>
        Compile for the specified Java SE release. Supported releases: 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14
  -s <directory>               Specify where to place generated source files
  --source <release>, -source <release>
        Provide source compatibility with the specified Java SE release. Supported releases: 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14
  --source-path <path>, -sourcepath <path>
        Specify where to find input source files
  --system <jdk>|none          Override location of system modules
  --target <release>, -target <release>
        Generate class files suitable for the specified Java SE release. Supported releases: 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14
  --upgrade-module-path <path>
        Override location of upgradeable modules
  -verbose                     Output messages about what the compiler is doing
  --version, -version          Version information
  -Werror                      Terminate compilation if warnings occur
```

Help me solve the problem. Thank you in advance!

Comment: I don't see any relation to Python. Further, it would help having a concrete list of steps to reproduce your issue. As a new user, also take the [tour] and read [ask].

Comment: The problem is not in Python, but in the fact that bulldozer does not work without javac, which for some reason is not installed on linux mint

Answer (score 1):

You need to install Java Development Kit. If you are using Debian based system (Ubuntu, Linux mint, etc.) just type in terminal: **sudo apt-get install openjdk-8-jdk**. On windows you must visit Java website and download Java JDK manually.

To check if you have installed Java JDK, type in console **javac -version**, you should see message like this: **javac 1.8.0_91**

Comment: or proprietary https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/install/installation-jdk-linux-platforms.html

Comment: the problem is that I already installed java c 14

Comment: I have javaс 14.0.2 installed